# How to exclude retweet when scraping tweet with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I want to scrape data from twitter with tweepy but i dont want the retweet include in it. How to do it?

This is my code:

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = 'xx'
consumer_secret = 'xx'
access_token = 'xx'
access_token_secret = 'xx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvpefile = open ('netflix.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvpefile)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=["netflix"], 
                       lang="id",
                       since="2020-07-8", 
                       tweet_mode = 'extended', 
                       trucated='false').items(200):

print(tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.full_text)
csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
```

i've try put

```
                    count=None,
                    since_id=None,
                    max_id=None,
                    trim_user=False,
                    exclude_replies=False,
                    contributor_details=False,
                    include_entities=True):
```

and

```
q=["netflix -filter:retweets"]
```

in api.search, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

By adding a quick check to see if the tweet text string begins with `rt @` you should be able to stop retweets from appearing in your csv document.

```
import tweepy
import csv

consumer_key = 'xx'
consumer_secret = 'xx'
access_token = 'xx'
access_token_secret = 'xx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

csvpefile = open ('netflix.csv', 'a')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvpefile)


for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,
                       q=["netflix"], 
                       lang="id",
                       since="2020-07-8", 
                       tweet_mode = 'extended', 
                       trucated='false').items(200):

# could go without this variable it just makes it easier
tweettext = str(tweet.full_text.lower().encode('ascii',errors='ignore'))

# check if the tweet starts with the format for a retweet
if tweettext.startswith("rt @") == False:
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.id, tweet.full_text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Comment: If that still doesnt work edit the check line to be `if tweettext.startswith("rt @") == False and hasattr(tweet, 'retweeted_status') == False:
`

Answer (score 0):

To exclude retweets in your search, try with :

```
q=["netflix -filter:retweets"]
```

NB: Using tweepy is not "scraping". You are using the public API.

Comment: it doesn't work, the RT's still exist in my csv file. Is it crawling?